# Angular 6 Component Reusable other than app component

Tags: angular

Is it possible to use a component to be used in other component aside from app.commponent ?

Usually I use ng-content and selector to inject my component to app-component. But it does not work if I use it on other components besides app-component.

app.component.html

```
<app-mycomponent></app-mycomponent>
```

this works only for app.component. Is there a way to use it to other components?

I use router-outlet to render my other components.

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

in this form. The component I want to inject in, is being rendered by router-outlet.

Comment: Make sure you have exported the components in other module.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by exported. But I did import it to the component that I want. Even added it in app module entry and declarations. But no luck

Comment: share your app.module.ts and the component you want to show